# OpenLayers zoom to USA with Bounds

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Hello I am using OpenLayers, and I would like make zoom map to show all USA territory
I have added next code to my JS file

```
zoomMapTo: function (x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(x1, y1, x1, y2);
    map.zoomToExtent(bounds,4);
}
```

But I don't know that coordenate should I use 
I tring to call it like

```
zoomMapTo(-19838714.3168264, 2146075.00656018, 19971050.5931969, 11542768.518094);
```

or

```
zoomMapTo(-120, 20, -70, 50);
```

But I go to some please in ocean
That coordinate I must use ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: To know what the coords need to be you will have to use the same projection as your map.  If you show more of your map initialisation code someone might be able to help.

Comment: thank I find out soulution i need just convert it to  EPSG:4326 var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds();
        bounds.extend(new OpenLayers.LonLat(x1, y1).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), appOL.mapobj.map.getProjectionObject()));
        bounds.extend(new OpenLayers.LonLat(x2, y2).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), appOL.mapobj.map.getProjectionObject()));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out soulution i need just convert it to `EPSG:4326`:

```
var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(); 
bounds.extend(new OpenLayers.LonLat(x1, y1).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), appOL.mapobj.map.getProjectionObject())); 
bounds.extend(new OpenLayers.LonLat(x2, y2).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), appOL.mapobj.map.getProjectionObject()
```